# Getting a TypeError in vscode

Tags: javascript, node.js

So, I'm coding a Discord Bot right now.
Now I've got an error after trying to run my bot.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\azoq\Desktop\snowhaze\index.js:15:21)
```

It's about the following lines:

```
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => 
file.endsWith('.js'));

for(const file of commandFiles){
   const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

   client.commands.set(command.name, command);
 }
```

The code won't format as supposed btw.
I appreciate any kind of support!

Comment: As the error indicates, the client.commands seems to be undefined. Double check what client is and if it has commands property

Comment: @szczocik client is the following: const client = new Discord.Client();

Comment: Do you have the API documentation reference? Can't find it.
Did you try logging the client and client.commands to see if they are defined?